# Class and attribute problem

Tags: javascript, scope

I wanted to play with geolocation API on my Android. I know that there is a "navigator" object that is defined and that should be used to aquire user position. So, I created this sample code:

```
function GeolocationTester()
{
    // here I want to store all acquired locations
    this.locations = new Array();
    alert("this.locations defined: " + this.locations);
    this.onSuccess = function(position)
    {
        alert("Entered onSuccess");
        alert("this.locations defined: " + this.locations);
    }

    this.onError = function(error)
    {
        alert("error acquiring location");
    }
    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(this.onSuccess, this.onError, { enableHighAccuracy: true });
}
```

And it doesn't work for me. Each time watchPosition call onSuccess the this.locations field isn't defined (and it is defined just after new Array). I known that I'm doing somethind wrong, but as it is one of my JavaScript attempts, not sure what. So, anybody could find a problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the scoping of `this`. When the `onSuccess` or `onError` is called, `this` isn't bound to the object containing the `locations` array. You need to create an explicit variable outside of the functions to which the array should be assigned and then use this variable in the callbacks, like this:

```
var allLocations = this.locations = [a, b, c];
this.onSuccess = function(position) {
    alert("allLocations: " + allLocations);
    alert("this.locations: " + this.locations);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Its cause you using `this`. This will change cause its depends on the context your function is calling on. Just use the scope of the function to declare location:

```
function GeolocationTester()
{
    // here I want to store all acquired locations
    var locations = [];
    alert("locations defined: " + locations);

    function onSuccess(position)    {
        alert("Entered onSuccess");
        alert("locations defined: " + locations);
    }

   function onError(error){
        alert("error acquiring location");
   }


 navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, { enableHighAccuracy: true });
}
```

To really understand what `this` read this blog post http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/chapter-3-this/

Answer (score 0):

Try to define `onSuccess` like this:

```
this.onSuccess = (function(locations) {
    return function(position)
           {
               alert("Entered onSuccess");
               alert("this.locations defined: " + locations);
           }
})(this.locations);
```